# PHP: Displaying a value dependent on input

Tags: php

In my view I have the following select menu that states what type of form types are available:

```
<label for="add_fields_type">Type: </label>
<select name="add_fields_type" id="add_fields_type">
    <option value="input">Input</option>
    <option value="textarea">Text Area</option>
    <option value="radiobutton">Radio Button</option>
    <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
</select>
```

In my controller I currently have the following but I am unsure how to make is so that if `$_REQUEST['add_fields_type']` is `=` to lets say `radiobutton` then it will display that respective code.

**Controller:**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'])) 
        {

            echo $_REQUEST['add_fields_type'];
        }
```

Comment: you can use switch case for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'])) {

    if ($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'input') {

            // echo stuff for input
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'textarea') {

            // echo stuff for textarea
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'radiobutton') {

            // echo stuff for radiobutton
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'] == 'checkbox') {

            // echo stuff for checkbox
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using the switch code that swapnesh mentioned (slightly more concise than having multiple if statements and will stop when it hits the right case):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['add_fields_type']))
{
    switch($_REQUEST['add_fields_type'])
    {
        case('input'):
            // echo stuff for input
            break;
        case('textarea'):
            // echo stuff for textarea
            break;
        case('radiobutton'):
            // echo stuff for radiobutton
            break;
        case('checkbox'):
            // echo stuff for checkbox
            break;
        default:
            // echo stuff if the other cases fall through
            break;
    }
}
```